# Getting the dynamic states with ui-sref

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

This My ng-repeat Code. This is Main Menu. consist of breakfast,lunch...etc. i Want to get States for this dynamically.

below code is html

```
<li class="mega-menu" ng-repeat="gethead in details" >
<a style="padding-left:10px;padding-right:10px;" class="level-top" href="" 
ui-sref="menu.breakfast({_id:gethead._id})">{{gethead.ctgname}}</a></li>
```

its my Script in app.config

```
  $stateProvider.state("menu.breakfast", {url:"/breakfast/:_id",
templateUrl:"partials/breakfast/breakfastveg.html",controller:"MyCtrl",
         resolve:{
                breakfast :["$http","$stateParams",function($http,$stateParams){
                              var url="menu/" + $stateParams._id;
                               return $http.get(url).then(function(res){
                               return res.data;})   
                           }]
                           }})
```

It is not working.... please Help me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with ng-click:

```
...ng-click="goToState(gethead)">
```

And in controller:

```
...
$scope.goToState = function(gethead) {
    $state.go(gethead._id);
}
...
```

Comment: Sorry dude. not working...Any Way Thanks for your Quick Response @Boris Parnikel

Comment: sorry, i mistaked. if gethead._id is a name of state, then you should to do $state.go(gethead._id)